# URLScheme Issue in ios10 itms-books is disallowed

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10

[image: URL scheme not allowed error]

**Even the CFBundleURL scheme is set to string and added see the info.plist:**
[image: PLIST settings]

**See the Plist settings have itms-books in url scheme.**

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is not the `itms-books` entry you selected, but *several rows above*, where you define your own URL schemes (e.g. those schemes that your app will support). Here you declare that your app will be an "editor" for iBooks -- and I think Apple won't allow this.

There is another problem with `fbauth2` in the same section -- I don't think your app will *implement* facebook authentification, you just want to use it (as it correctly added in the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` section).

Just remember:

- `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` contains the schemes that your app wants to use (e.g. these are "foreigen" schemes of other apps)
- `CFBundleURLSchemes` contains your own schemes (e.g. those schemes your app implements/exports; called by other other apps)

Comment: so what actually we need to change in plist to make it working?Also any code changes need too? Thanks

Comment: No, you just need to edit the plist file. It's the entry named "URL types" (which contains the problematic item "Item 2 (Editor)"/"URL schemes"/"itms-books" and also Item 3 ... "fbauth2". Just delete those.

Comment: okay but will it not break any function of our app that uses it ? and why you asking to remove fbauth2 as it was not showing any error at validation?

Comment: If your App implements the fbauth2 "service" then keep it. If your App uses fbauth2 from the fb App, then remove it.

Comment: it does uses fb auth service and it does not requires an fb app it goes to browser even if app is not their for auth so need to keep it.And for itms-books ?

Comment: The correct position is underneth `LSApplicationQuerySchemes` (for both), not under `URL types`. Again: If some other app is going to "start" your app, then you provide a key under `URL types`. If your app is going to call any other app, you enter their key under `LSApplicationQuerySchemes`. Since I suppose you don't write the iBooks app currently, you must not hi-jack their URL scheme `itms-book` under `URL types` (you don't provide an iBook service), but you want to _use_ iBooks (to display anything), therefore you only put it under `LSApplicationQuerySchemes`